# Creating a very large sparse matrix csv from a list of condensed data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, numpy

I have a dictionary of the format:

```
{
  "sample1": set(["feature1", "feature2", "feature3"]),
  "sample2": set(["feature1", "feature4", "feature5"]),
}
```

where I have 20M `sample`s and 150K unique features.

I want to convert this into a csv of the format:

```
sample,feature1,feature2,feature3,feature4,feature5
sample1,1,1,1,0,0
sample2,1,0,0,1,1
```

What I have done so far:

1. `ALL_FEATURES = list(set(features))`
2. ```
   with open("features.csv", "w") as f:
       f.write("fvecmd5," + ",".join([str(x) for x in ALL_FEATURES]) + "\n")
       fvecs_lol = list(fvecs.items())
       fvecs_keys, fvecs_values = zip(*fvecs_lol)
       del fvecs_lol
       tmp = [["1" if feature in featurelist else "0" for feature in ALL_FEATURES] for featurelist in fvecs_values]
       for i, entry in enumerate(tmp):
           f.write(fvecs_keys[i] + "," + ",".join(entry) + "\n")
   ```

But this is running very slow. Are there faster ways? Maybe leveraging Numpy/Cython?

Comment: you could check one hot function from tensorflow or sklearn

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), which produces a sparse matrix and then create a SparseDataFrame:

```
In [49]: s = pd.SparseSeries(d).astype(str).str.replace(r"[{,'}]",'')

In [50]: s
Out[50]:
sample1    feature1 feature2 feature3
sample2    feature1 feature5 feature4
dtype: object

In [51]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [52]: cv = CountVectorizer()

In [53]: r = pd.SparseDataFrame(cv.fit_transform(s),
                                s.index, 
                                cv.get_feature_names(), 
                                default_fill_value=0)

In [54]: r
Out[54]:
         feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4  feature5
sample1         1         1         1         0         0
sample2         1         0         0         1         1
```

Comment: This ran for nearly 11 hours on my machine and then ran out of memory :( I am upvoting this answer cuz it works on smaller data sets.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you need ?

```
pd.Series(d).apply(','.join).str.get_dummies(sep=',')
Out[50]: 
         feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4  feature5
sample1         1         1         1         0         0
sample2         1         0         0         1         1
```

You can add `to_csv` at the end

How about this

```
s=pd.Series(d).to_frame('v')

s.v=list(map(','.join,s.v.values))

s.v.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
Out[86]: 
         feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4  feature5
sample1         1         1         1         0         0
sample2         1         0         0         1         1
```

Comment: This is a really great one-liner. I ran this and got a memory-error though :( I am upvoting this answer because this is exactly what I was looking for, but it isn't something that solved my problem

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge update another method , should be faster than apply

Comment: Just checking the other solutions.. please give me a few minutes. They haven't run out of memory yet ;)

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem isn't with speed, it's with memory consumption (Since you said `apply` should be faster)

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge Please let me know, The finial one from me will be chunk

Comment: :( Ran out of memory in the last step. I have 64GB RAM

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge I will say , you can chunk it at the last step, and storage them into local database , then after finish you can query them out

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to convert the CSV from a sparse representation to a dense representation.

How?
You could load the csv into a sparse matrix (check out [scipy.coo_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) which sort of fits your case), convert to a dense numpy array (with np.array()) and save it back as a CSV (maybe going through list-of-lists first)

(OR you could use some fancy pandas coding as someone else suggested.)

HOWEVER, the real question is, why do you want to store such a large dataset in a dense format? It would be extremely inefficient in memory / disk space, and the conversion SHOULD take a long time for a large dataset.
Specifically, if your dataset has 20M samples with 150k features, a dense representation would not fit in your memory and likely not even your disk.

Comment: Its actually the other way round. I have a dense representation and want to create a sparse representation. I need to do this so that I can make a scatter plot out of it

Comment: I guess the word sparse is used to describe different things.
A dictionary format is sparse, a scipy.**sparse**.coo_matrix is sparse, a numpy array is dense (Here, the word sparse refers to a property of the data structure, not the stored values... )

Comment: Got it. I need to make this as an intermediate step for input into DataShader which wants *Point(x-coord, y-coord)* to plot. So once I have it in this format, I will extrapolate that into `x` and `y` values